# Changing my parallel arrays into a single struct?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, structure

`roll` and `exp` were originally both one-dimensional arrays of size 13 declared in `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
int roll;
int exp;
} Roll;


int  main ( void )
{
 char quit;

 printf("\n A simulation of dice rolls to determine roll frequencey:\n");

 do {

   FILE *fp;
   int input;
   int num1, num2, sum, total = 0,i;
   Roll tosses[13] = { {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5},
                       {0, 6}, {0, 5}, {0, 4}, {0, 3}, {0, 2}, {0, 1} };

// ALGORITHM 2: Prompt user for number of rolls and store input.

    printf("\n Please enter number of rolls: ");
    scanf(" %d", &input);

// ALGORITHM 3: Calculate roll frequency.

   for (i = 0; i < input ; i++)
   {

           sum=0;
           num1=1+rand()%6;
           num2=1+rand()%6;
           sum=num1+num2;
           tosses[sum].roll++;

   }

   for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
   {
           total+=tosses[i].roll;

// ALGORITHM 4: Display results.

    printf("\n\n");
    printf(" Roll:    Expected(%%):            Session(%%):\n");

   for (i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
   {

       printf(" %2d       %9f%%        %9f%%    (%d / %d)\n", i,
       100.0*tosses[i].exp/36, 100.0*tosses[i].roll/input, tosses[i].roll, input);
   }

 fp = fopen("results.dat", "w");
 if (fp == NULL) {
 printf("I couldn't open results.dat for writing.\n");
 exit(0);

   }


      fprintf(fp,"\n Roll:    Expected(%%):            Session(%%):\n");

   for (i = 2; i <= 12; i++)

     fprintf(fp, "%2d       %9f%%        %9f%%    (%d / %d)\n", i,
     100.0*tosses[i].exp/36, 100.0*tosses[i].roll/input, tosses[i].roll, input);

// ALGORITHM 5: Prompt user to roll again or quit.

printf("\n Would you like to run simulation again? (Type: Y / N ): ");
   scanf(" %c", &quit);

} while (quit == 'y' || quit == 'Y');

return(0);

}
```

Comment: btw ive been working on this all morning and really just cant grasp how to set this up...

Comment: What parallell arrays?  I only see one array

Comment: the arrays ROLL and EXP of both size 13 makes them parallel does it not?

Comment: You're not updating *parallel* arrays. there is only one update target (`ROLL[]`). And to be completely frank, how you have it setup *without* stuffing the data into a struct is plenty-good for what the code does. If this is an assignment, I'd do it, but begrudgingly. Your layout is actually *good* as is (imho). (unrelated: was this: `%d%` intentional in your format string?).

Comment: How would i go about stuffing the data into a struct maybe im not seeing how to do it because liek you said it seems pointless unfortunatly the requirements i have to comply with are... Quote on quote, "Replacing the parallel arrays with a single structure, THEN after displaying the results to the screen, write the results to a file named results.dat
-Each time the user runs the simulation, the new results will overwrite the old results in the data file." --- does this make any sense to you?

Comment: `" %d%"` should be `" %d"`

Comment: `} while (quit == 'y' || quit == 'Y');` This does not look good...

Comment: thank you for your critiques, how would you have performed looping this task (rolling dice user inputed amount of times) at the users will...

Answer (score 2):

There is no compelling reason to change parallel arrays to a struct, but this is one way:

```
int ROLL[13]={0};
int EXP[13] ={0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3,2,1};
```

To

```
struct {
     int  roll;
     int  exp;
} tosses [13] = {
    {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5},
    {0, 6}, {0, 5}, {0, 4}, {0, 3}, {0, 2}, {0, 1}
}
```

So, instead of `ROLL[sum]++`, it would be

```
++tosses[sum].roll;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply i dont understand the use of doing this either but my professor would like us to fulfill the requirments of...-Replacing the parallel arrays with a single structure  
-After displaying the results to the screen, write the results to a file named results.dat
-Each time the user runs the simulation, the new results will overwrite the old results in the data file

Comment: anyways i gave this a shot and am getting a compile error of subscripted value is neither array nor a pointer

Comment: @user3587150:  If you used exactly the code I posted (less the excerpt from yours), it should compile fine.  If not, post your code (by updating your question) and I'll help track it down.

Comment: ok updated the code and it compiles...the only thing i thought tho was that my professor taught us to use prototypes and put the struct above main...? what i have here is fine tho? (ie. struct declared below main? He mentioned that we are not allowed to use global variables if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user3587150:  There are good reasons to use global variables and (other) good reasons not to use them.  For example, device drivers for most operating systems *require* global variables.  Your professor should make clear *why* each is a good idea, not just rattle off mindless rules.